# Oracle Installation In HP-UX

Tags: unix, oracle

I wanna install Oracle 10g in HP UX 11.3(RISC Machine). As per the Oracle installation pre-requisites, it requires HP C/aC++ Compiler to be installed along with the requisite patches for the same. The problem is the HP C/aC++ compiler is available in the form of Developer's Bundle which has to be purchased from HP. MY Question Is: are there any alternate freeware C/C++ compiler available which can run in the HP UX and whether is it a mandatory requirement to have a C/C++ Compiler for Installing Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try GCC. http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801?ciid=2a08725cc2f02110725cc2f02110275d6e10RCRD

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the oracle client contains an installable compiler that should be ok for that purpose.

Comment: can u share any link reg the IIRC Client?